# Construct QPushButton with QIcon alignleft and text center align

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpushbutton

I would like to create `QPushButton` with `QIcon` left align (not to the center as default) and text center align. I don't want to use a style sheet. I know that might be possibly using `QPainter` but I wasn't able to do it. I had little clue and tried this code:

```
void MyPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    QStyleOptionButton opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);
    painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignLeft, opt.icon);
    painter.drawItemText(opt.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, palette(), 1, opt.text);
    painter.drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelButtonCommand, opt);
}
```

which produces this error message

> no matching function for call to 'QStylePainter::drawItemPixmap(QRect&, Qt::AlignmentFlag, QIcon&)' painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, opt.icon);

What's wrong with code above?

Comment: We also need to know what actually happened when you ran the code and what you didn't like about it.

Comment: this error code error: no matching function for call to 'QStylePainter::drawItemPixmap(QRect&, Qt::AlignmentFlag, QIcon&)'
   painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, opt.icon);

Comment: @mumulala The answer belongs in an edit to the question, not in a comment :)

Comment: There isn't enough code shown to know what's wrong. For all we know you've set up your widget incorrectly with regards to size management, etc. This question is unanswerable without a complete code that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Once a question has an answer you can't radically change it such that it invalidates that answer. If you need to, ask another question.

Comment: @rodolk: [Your review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182748) is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322010/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-attempting-to-revert-a-question)

Comment: @wogsland: [Your review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182748) is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322010/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-attempting-to-revert-a-question)

Comment: @River: [Your review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12182748) is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322010/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-attempting-to-revert-a-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're getting

> this error code error: no matching function for call to 'QStylePainter::drawItemPixmap(QRect&, Qt::AlignmentFlag, QIcon&)' painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, opt.icon);

because `drawItemPixmap` draws... a pixmap. Not an icon. So all you need to do is get the icons pixmap using the `pixmap()` accessor.

change

```
painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignLeft, opt.icon);
```

to

```
// or whaever size you want
painter.drawItemPixmap(opt.rect, Qt::AlignLeft, opt.icon.pixmap(QSize(16,16)));
```

Comment: thank you @Nicholas for respons, i changed the code and it didn't produce any error but icon and text are invisible.

Comment: @mumulala it's like Kuba said, without specific code, images of the output, and error messages, we can't replicate the problem, and there's not a lot we can do.

Comment: if i remove this line painter.drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelButtonCommand, opt); QIcon is on the left and text is on the center but no button behaviour.

Comment: @mumulala to get the button behavior,  you'd have to paint each permutation of `opt.state` and all the button features individually. Honestly you are _way_ better off if you just use stylesheets. It's much simpler, much more flexible, and much less code to write.